# execute query according to condition

Tags: java, mysql

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<SelectItemsDTO> listItem = new ArrayList<SelectItemsDTO>();
    try {
        StringBuilder query =new StringBuilder();

        query = query.append(SLCMQueryConstant.GET_CollegeChid_LIST);

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());
        pstmt.setInt(1,commonDto.getOrgID());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        int pid= 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
        pid= rs.getInt("organization_parent_id");
        }

        if(pid!= 0)
        {
            query = query.append(SLCMQueryConstant.GET_CollegeSub_LIST.toString());

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());

        }
        else
        {

            query = query.append(SLCMQueryConstant.GET_College_LIST.toString());
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());

        }


       pstmt.setInt(1,commonDto.getOrgID());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            SelectItemsDTO itemTo = new SelectItemsDTO();

            itemTo.setItemCode(rs.getString("Organization_Name"));
            itemTo.setItemIds(rs.getInt("Organization_ID"));

            listItem.add(itemTo);

        }
    }
public static final String GET_College_LIST= " SELECT Organization_Name,Organization_ID FROM m_organization_master WHERE organization_parent_id = ? ";
public static final String GET_CollegeSub_LIST = " SELECT  Organization_Name,Organization_ID FROM m_organization_master WHERE Organization_ID = ? ";
```

I want to execute query according to if condition .I am getting PID value from database and then used as if condition .This code seems an error no value specified for parameter 1 I have already initialized parameter for passing the values.

Comment: what do `SLCMQueryConstant.GET_CollegeChid_LIST` and `SLCMQueryConstant.GET_CollegeSub_LIST` return?

Comment: it is returning two value organization_Id,organization_Name.

Comment: both are different query in GET_CollegeChid_LIST is returning college list according to university in GET_CollegeSub_LIST  is returning university name.  and both should come in dropdown as selectedItemDTO

Comment: I found solution above I should use normal prepare statement instead of QueryBuilder  String querydis=SLCMQueryConstant.GET_CollegeChid_LIST.toString();
  
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(querydis.toString());